# Difference between Play and Resume in XNA SoundEffects class

Tags: audio, xna, xna-4.0, soundeffect

What is the difference between the Play and Resume methods in the XNA SoundEffects class? Both seem to start playing the sound at the current sound position. Can't I basically always use Play()?

I am using XNA 4 (with the latest updates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is simple:

- `Play` starts the execution of a `SoundEffect` from the beginning of the audio file
- `Resume` is the dual of `Pause`, and let you resume a `SoundEffect` from the moment you called `Pause`

**UPDATE**

If you're using `SoundEffectInstance` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance_methods.aspx)'s the answer to your question.

> Play method plays or resumes a SoundEffectInstance

So the difference is that you can do both things only using `Play`, `Resume` of course can't be called if the sound effect is not paused.

Comment: But this seems to not be the case. A "Play" applied to a paused SoundEffect does exactly the same as "Resume" i.a. continue the sound at the position where it were paused and NOT play it from the beginning.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the type of audio file you are using.

Answer (score 1):

First, what version of XNA are you using? And second, I believe Play and Resume are SoundEffectInstance class methods and the difference is that you can't **START** a sound effect *(that has never been started)* by using Resume.